# Object creating and accessing inside a jframe code behind not work

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have created a class called player and beginner (`public class Beginner extends Player`)

then I tried to access beginner from the main class. It worked.
screenshot down below.
[image: Main object create and access]

Then I tried to create another object and access that object from the jframe. It allows me to create the object (`Beginner b1= new Beginner();`)
But does not allow to access that object. It says *identifier expected*.

Here's the screenshot inside the jframe.
[image: Inside jframe]

How can I access through the jframe code behind?? What causes this ?

note: I am still a beginner to java. So please do not misunderstand me for asking these type of questions. Thank you ..!

Comment: You need to access the members from a method or block. You can only declare the variables there.

Comment: 1) In future questions, don't post screenshots of the IDE, but the text of the code and error or warning message. Text can be searched, while text in images cannot. 2) This problem has nothing to do with the IDE, but Java and the compiler. Don't add the [tag:netbeans] tag.

Comment: ok.. From now on I'll adhere to that ..!

Answer (score 0):

You can't call members like that unless you're doing an assignment.

```
public class A {
    void foo() { ... }
    int shoo() { ... }
}

public class b {
    A a = new A();
    // can't call a.foo() here

    int x = a.shoo(); // valid

    {
        a.foo(); //valid
    }


    bar () {
        a.foo(); // valid
    }
}
```